# Binding in User Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding, user-controls

let's say I've got this code (in Winforms):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class SomeControl : UserControl
{
    private SomeClass inClass;

    public string MyName { get; set; }

    public SomeControl(SomeClass someClass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.inClass = someClass;

        SetupBinding();
    }

    private void SetupBinding()
    {
        this.DataBindings.Clear();
        this.DataBindings.Add("MyName", this.inClass, "Name");
    }
}
```

If I'll change the the value of SomeClass.Name outside the user control, the property MyName never changes. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: A `UserControl` vs a `Form` works OK (bidirectionally) but a `UserControl` vs another `UserControl` doesn't work. That's a little strange because `UserControl` inherits from `Control` which implements `IBindableComponent`, I can create my own bindable component which works with other controls and with each other too. There is something special here about `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SomeClass** must impelement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) or have event named **NameChanged** if you want bidirectional data binding. You can implement it yourself, but I highly recommend [Fody.PropertyChanged](http://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) project.

PS: I wrote some extension method to create binding more easier and refactoring friendly way. In your case it would look like this:

```
this.BindTo(inClass, c => c.MyName , m => m.Name);
```

The method itself:

```
public static class BindingExtensions
{
    public static Binding BindTo<TControl, TControlProperty, TModel, TModelProperty>(this TControl control, TModel model, Expression<Func<TControl, TControlProperty>> controlProperty, Expression<Func<TModel, TModelProperty>> modelProperty, string format = null)
        where TControl : Control
    {
        var controlPropertyName = ((MemberExpression)controlProperty.Body).Member.Name;
        var modelPropertyName = ((MemberExpression)modelProperty.Body).Member.Name;

        var formattingEnabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(format);
        var binding = control.DataBindings.Add(controlPropertyName, model, modelPropertyName, formattingEnabled, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        if (formattingEnabled)
        {
            binding.FormatString = format;
        }
        return binding;
    }
}
```